# Creating multiple plots with few lines of code in R

Tags: r, function, performance, plot, cross-correlation

I want to plot multiple time-series variables in the same plot so that I can see how the time series lags line up. I will have a few different plots for different groups of data, and each of those plots will represent a different group of data, although each plot will have variables with the same name.

I could do it individually, one variable at a time. But I have like a hundred variables.

Here is an example of my dataset where `lag` is the lag point (from the `ccf()`) and each `var` is the ACF of a different variable at that lag point.

```
sampledf <- data.frame(
  lag = -10:10,
  var1 = rnorm(21),
  var2 = rnorm(21),
  var3 = rnorm(21)
)
```

Now I could plot them fairly easily like this:

```
plot(sampledf$lag,
     sampledf$var1, 
     type = "l",
     col = 1,
     xlab = "Lag",
     ylab = "ACF")
lines(sampledf$lag,
     sampledf$var2,
      type = "l",
      col = 2)
lines(sampledf$lag,
     sampledf$var3,
      type = "l",
      col = 3)
legend("topright",                          
       c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3"),
       lty = 1,
       col = 1:3)
```

But then I am doing each variable manually. And if I wanted to view the correlations in a different way-for example, one plot with `var1` from each of `sampledf1`, `sampledf2`, through `sampledf20`, I would have to start all over.

Is there a way to automate this in fewer lines of code?
This is just beyond my level of R programming but I realise this probably has something to do with functions and things (R is mainly a "stats" tool in my work).

I'm also open to different functions to view cross-correlations in different ways if there's a completely different (yet easier) way to achieve this.

Comment: You are varying color for each of your variables, but if you have *"like a hundred variables"* then you will either run out of colors or have a gradient so minute that readers will have a difficult time differentiating lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely very quickly run out of colors, but you can do this:

## base R

```r
plot(sampledf$lag,
     sampledf$var1, 
     type = "n",
     col = 1,
     xlab = "Lag",
     ylab = "ACF")
Map(function(y, col) lines(sampledf$lag, y, col=col, type="l"),
    sampledf[,-1], seq_len(ncol(sampledf)-1))
legend("topright",                          
       c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3"),
       lty = 1,
       col = 1:3)
```

[image: base R plot]

## ggplot2

This works much better in a "long" format.

```r
library(ggplot2)
tidyr::pivot_longer(sampledf, -lag) |>
  ggplot(aes(lag, value, color = name, group = name)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: ggplot grob]